# inputing python list into Teradata SQL

Tags: python, sql, teradata

I'm having a problem executing this SQL statement with a python list injection. I'm new to teradata SQL, and I'm not sure if this is the appropriate syntax for injecting a list into the where clause.

```
conn = teradatasql.connect(host='PROD', user='1234', password='1234', logmech='LDAP')
    
    l = ["Comp-EN Routing", "Comp-COLLABORATION"]
    l2 = ["PEO", "TEP"]
    l3 = ["TCV"]
    crsr = conn.cursor()
    query = """SELECT SOURCE_ORDER_NUMBER 
               FROM DL_.BV_DETAIL
               WHERE (LEVEL_1 IN ? AND LEVEL_2 IN ?) or LEVEL_3 IN ?"""
    
       
    crsr.executemany(query, [l,l2,l3])
    conn.autocommit = True
```

I keep getting this error

```
Version 17.0.0.2] [Session 308831600] [Teradata Database] [Error 3939] There is a mismatch between the number of parameters specified and the number of parameters required.
```

Comment: Each `?` parameter marker can only be replaced with a single value, not a list of values. And the syntax for SQL `IN` requires parentheses around the list of values. Particularly if the number of items in each list can vary, you may want to consider formatting the value lists into the text of the query rather than passing values as parameters. Or else you may have to dynamically generate a statement with the correct number of `?` for each list..

Comment: Note that `executemany` will try to execute `query` once for each list of values in the list of lists. If there are three `?` in the query, each of those lists of parameters is expected to contain 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer this, but if I found the question someone else will in the future too.

`executemany` in `teradatasql` requires that second parameter to be a ["sequence of sequences"](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/). The most common type of `sequence` we generally use in Python is a `list`. Essentially you need a list that contains, for each element in the list, a list.

In your case this may look like:

```
myListOfLists=[['level1valueA','level1valueA','level3valueA'],['level1valueB','level1valueB','level3valueB']]
```

Your SQL statement will be executed twice, once for each list in your list.

In your case though I suspect you are wanting to find any combination of the values that you have stored in your three lists which is entirely different ball of wax and is going to take some creativity (generate a list of list with all possible combinations and submit to `executemany` OR construct a SQL statement that can take in multiple comma delimited lists of values, form a cartesian product, and test for hits)

Answer (score -1):

Want to add some regarding SELECT statement and executemany method: to retrieve all records returned by your query you will need to call   .nextset() followed by .fetchall() as many times as it will become False. First .fetchall() will give you only first result (first list of parameters specified).

```
...
with teradatasql.connect(connectionstring) as conn:
     with conn.cursor() as cur:
          cur.executemany("SELECT COL1 FROM THEDATABASE.THETABLE WHERE COL1 = ?;",[['A'],['B']])
          result=cur.fetchall() # will bring you only rows matching 'A'
          if (cur.nextset()):
               result2=cur.fetchall() # results for 'B'
...
```

Comment: This answer looks very unclear. Try using some code formatting https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and add more explanation